$G$ a group s.t. $|G|=12$. Why $g\cdot S=S$ for all $S$ and all $g\in G$.
Let $G$ be a group and $\mathcal S$ be all subsets of cardianality $4$, i.e. $$\mathcal S=\{S\subset G\mid |S|=4\}.$$
The aim of the exercise is to prove that there exist a subgroup $H$ of $G$ with cardinality 4.
Define $$\cdot : G\times \mathcal S\to \mathcal S; (g,S)\mapsto g\cdot S,$$
where for $S=\{s_1;s_2;s_3;s_4\}\subset G$, $$g\cdot S=\{gs_1,gs_2,gs_3,gs_4\}.$$

1) Prove that $G\times \mathcal S\to \mathcal S; (g,S)\mapsto g\cdot S$ is a group action (done).
2) Prove that $2\nmid |\mathcal S|$ (done using the fact that $|\mathcal S|=\binom{12}{4}$).
3) Prove that there is $S_0\in \mathcal S$ s.t. its orbits $\mathcal O_{S_0}$ is not even (done using class equation).
4) Let $H=G_{S_0}$ the stabilizer of $S_0$.
4.1)   Prove that $|H|\in \{4,12\}$. (Done using the fact that $|\mathcal O_{S_0}|\in \{1,3\}$ and using the fact that $\frac{|G|}{|G_{S_0}|}=|\mathcal O_{S_0}|$).
4.2) Prove that $|H|=12$ is impossible. This is where I'm stuck.

Q1) Suppose $|H|=12$. What I remarked is that $g\cdot S_0=S_0$ for all $g\in G$. Thanks to Chat GPT, it seems to implies that $g\cdot S=S$ for all $g\in G$ and all $ S\in \mathcal S$. However, I can't prove it. Could someone help ?
Q2) Why would it be a contradiction ?

Attempts
The only thing I can see, is that if $S_0=\{s_0^1,s_0^2,s_0^3,s_0^4\}$ then $g\cdot s_0^i\in \{s_0^1,s_0^2,s_0^3,s_0^4\}$ for all $g\in G$, but why will it implies that $g\cdot S=S$ for all $S\in \mathcal S$ and all $g\in G$ ?

If $|H|=12$ then every element of $G$ stabilises $S_0=\{x,y,z,w\}$.
Let $a\notin S_0$. Then with $g=ax^{-1}$ we have $g\in G=H$ and yet $g\cdot x=a\notin S_0$.
Hence $|H|=12$ is impossible.

would you agree with the fact that $g\cdot S=S$ for all $S\in \mathcal S$ or not ? and that $gs=s$ for all $s\in S\in \mathcal S$ if $|H|=12$ ? (it was what Chat GPT said, but I can't prove it... but maybe it's wrong. Thanks in advance.

Since $|H|=12$ is false we can deduce anything from that hypothesis. {ChatGPT is in my experience rubbish at group theory: presumably because it read too many rubbish proofs in the nursery.)
